# Android parse base64Binary pgm to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, base64, pgm

I need to convert a base64Binary-string in the format pgm to a bitmap in android. So I don't have an usual base64-encoded Bitmap.
The base64binary-string came from a xml file

`<ReferenceImage Type="base64Binary" Format="pgm" WidthPX="309" HeightPX="233" BytesPerPixel="1" >
NDY4Ojo9QEFDRUVHRklLTE9OUFFTU1VWV1hZWltZWVlZWlpbW1xdXmBgYmJjZGNlZWRkZGRlZmZnZ2ZnaWpqa21ub29ubm9vb3BwcHBxcHFyc3FzcnJzcnJydH[...]VlaW1xbWltcXFxcXFxd`.

```
Pattern.compile("<ReferenceImage .*>((?s).*)<\\/ReferenceImage>");
...
String sub = r; //base64binary string pattern-matched from xml file
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(sub.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP); //probably wrong decoding (needs to be ASCII to binary?)
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); //always null due to wrong byte-array
```

I think I understand that pgm images are typically stored as ASCII (like in my xml) or binary (0..255). I also think that `Base64.decode` needs the binary-variant, not the ASCII that I have.
However `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` doesn't understand the decoded byte-array and returns null.

So how can I convert my base64binary-pgm-ASCII-string to a valid byte-array in order to create a valid bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Base64-decoding is fine. But Android's `BitmapFactory` probably has no direct support for PGM format. I'm not sure how to add support to it, but it seems you could create a `Bitmap` using one of the `createBitmap(...)` factory methods quite easily.

See [PGM spec](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) for details on how to parse the header, or see [my implementation for Java SE](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-pnm/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/plugins/pnm/PNMHeaderParser.java) (if you look around, you'll also find a class that supports ASCII reading, if needed).

Could also be that there's no header, and that you can get the height/width from the XML. In that case, `dataOffset` will be `0` below.

When the header is parsed, you know width, height and where the image data starts:

```
int width, height; // from header
int dataOffset; // == end of header

// Create pixel array, and expand 8 bit gray to ARGB_8888
int[] pixels = new int[width  * height];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
         int gray = decodedString[dataOffset + i] & 0xff;
         pixels[i] = 0xff000000 | gray << 16 | gray << 8 | gray;
    }
}

Bitmap pgm = Bitmap.createBitmap(metrics, pixels, width, height, BitmapConfig.Config. ARGB_8888);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer!
You solved me the day!

I found a little error in your code, index i is never initialized or incremented.
I corrected your code and tested it, here is my code:

```
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromPgm(byte[] decodedString, int width, int height, int dataOffset){

    // Create pixel array, and expand 8 bit gray to ARGB_8888
    int[] pixels = new int[width  * height];
    int i = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int gray = decodedString[dataOffset + i] & 0xff;
            pixels[i] = 0xff000000 | gray << 16 | gray << 8 | gray;

            i++;
        }
    }
    Bitmap pgm = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, width, height, android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    return pgm;
}
```